# Url handling in web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I'm messing around with web.py for the first time, following Zed Shaw's Learn Python The Hard Way tut# 50. 
I'm trying to setup multiple webpages but can only seem to get index / to work.
I've tested everything else and it all works. When I replace

```
    urls = (
        '/', 'Index',
    )
```

with

```
    urls = (
        '/', 'foo',
    )
```

It loads my foo webpage

but when I try

```
    urls = (
    '/', 'Index',
    '/foo', 'FOO',

)
```

and enter localhost/foo:8080 in my browser I get an error connection refused
I've killed the server restarted it in between my code changes just to make sure and nothing changes.

I've tried multiple examples and used the cookbook examples to no avail , this one's got me stumped.
please show me what I'm Missing.

code below

app.py

```
    import web

    urls = (
        '/', 'Index',
        '/foo', 'FOO',

    )

    app = web.application(urls, globals())

    render = web.template.render('templates/')

    class Index(object):
        def GET(self):
            greeting = "Hello World"
            return render.index(greeting = greeting)

    class FOO(object):
        def GET(self):
            foo_greeting = "Hello foo"
            return render.foo(foos_greeting = foo_greeting)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

index.html

```
    $def with (greeting)

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Gothons Of Planet Percal #25</title>
        </head>
    <body>

    $if greeting:
        I just wanted to say <em style="color: green; font-size:              2em;">$greeting</em>.
    $else:
        <em>Hello</em>, world!

    </body>
    </html>
```

foo.html

```
    $def with (foos_greeting)

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Gothons Of Planet FOO</title>
        </head>
    <body>

    $if foos_greeting:
        I just wanted to say <em style="color: green; font-size:          2em;">$foos_greeting</em>.
    $else:
        <em>Hello</em>, foo foo!

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete comma after 'FOO' expression

```
urls = (
'/', 'Index',
'/foo', 'FOO'
)
```

and run

```
localhost:8080/foo
```

Comment: Comma isn't an issue, but yes, you need to have the port number `:8080` after the host, not after the `/foo` path.